# Best way to get file based on url in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, urlparse

I'm new to node and am trying to figure out what the best method is for using the URL path to read the corresponding HTML document. I know how to parse the URL, and I could just open the document with the exact name as the pathname (i.e. to open index.html, you use /index.html) but personally I think it looks sloppy to end a URL with ".html" after there is already a ".com". 
Essentially, my question is: how do I match the string that I get from the URL parse to a separate string that I will use to call the html file? 
My only idea is to use arrays: either `const home = ['/home', 'index.html']; const about = ['/about', 'about.html']` or `const paths = ['/home', '/about']; const files = ['index.html', 'about.html']` and then match the string I get to the corresponding array value. I suppose this wouldn't be too terrible, but there must be a better way, right?

Comment: I dont really understand what the goal is you are trying to achieve. What does the original URL look like? Am I understanding you correct that you have a URL http://test.com/file.html and you want to get the "file.html" part?

Comment: Would you be interested in the framework [expresss.js](https://expressjs.com/)? It has tools to respond to requests with files and makes things very simple in my opinion.

Comment: More like I want to get "file.html" from "test.com/path"